# Can I use an attribute selector for CONTAINS in queryselector()?

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

I would like to select an element based on a substring of href attribute.

I posted a question recently where I received an answer based on "starts with":

```
document.querySelector('#utility-menu a[href^="/email_check?lang="').textContent.trim();
```

But actually, the only constant from page to page will be `"lang="` within the href attribute. So `/email_check?` is page specific so I cannot use this variable on al pages.

Is it possible to modify my selector to return the textContent of any `<a>` element with the substring `"lang="` within it?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

All CSS selectors are documented on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) and specified in the [W3C CSSWG Selectors Level 4 overview](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#overview)<sup>1</sup> ([Archived link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210731051554/https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#overview)).

The one you need is

```css
#utility-menu a[href*="lang="]
```

> | Pattern | Represents |
> | --- | --- |
> | `E[foo*="bar"]` | An `E` element whose `foo` attribute value contains the substring `bar`. |

---

<sup>1</sup>: The CSSWG’s current work of the CSS Selectors Module is Selectors Level 4.
Not all of its features are supported in all browsers.
The Level 4 draft includes everything from Level 1 to Level 4.
Watch the “Level” table column.
Today’s browsers support at least up to Level 3, but check the [compatibility tables on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors#browser_compatibility) to be sure.

Answer (score 16):

Consider the following HTML element:

```
<div id="utility-menu">
  <a href="/email_check?lang=en-US">Hello, world!</a>
</div>
```

You can obtain the first [anchor element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) that has a [`href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-href) attribute containing `'lang='` and exists as a descendant of an element with an [`id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) equivalent to `'utility-menu'` using one of the following options:

```
// Using the [attr*=value] selector (best option)
document.querySelector('#utility-menu a[href*="lang="]')

// Using the find() method (alternative option)
[...document.querySelectorAll('#utility-menu a[href]')].find(e => e.href.includes('lang='))
```