# Does this jQuery feature exist?

Tags: jquery

I'm using the following code to change `Instagram` to `<i class='fab fa-instagram'/>`:

```
$("#LinkList3 .widget-content ul li a:contains(Instagram)").html("<i class='fab fa-instagram'/>");
```

But is it possible to look to the `#LinkList3 .widget-content ul li a` URL to check if it's contains `instagram.com` and if it's contains then append `<i class='fab fa-instagram'/>` to `#LinkList3 .widget-content ul li a` HTML markup?

Something like `$("#LinkList3 .widget-content ul li a:containsUrl(instagram.com)").html("<i class='fab fa-instagram'/>");`

Comment: You mean `a[href*='instagram.com']`? See [Can I use an attribute selector for CONTAINS in queryselector()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31773599/4642212).

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you :)